# Create nested JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have table in mysql like this

```
Parent | Child
LevelOne LevelTwo
LevelOne LevelThree
LevelTwo LevelFour
LevelTwo LevelFive
LevelFour LevelSix
```

I have stored them in an ArrayList like this

```
LevelOne | LevelTwo
LevelOne |LevelThree
LevelTwo | LevelFour
LevelTwo |LevelFive
LevelFour |LevelSix
```

And I m trying to convert this into JSON. This is what I have tried so far -

```
for(String v : values){
    String p = v.substring(0,v.indexOf("|"));//Parent
    String c = v.substring(v.indexOf("|")+1);//Child                        
    ObjectNode objectNode1 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    objectNode1.put("Parent", p);
    objectNode1.put("Children",c);
    arrayNode.add(objectNode1);
}
            System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(arrayNode));
```

However this is wrong because it prints like this

```
[ {
  "Folder" : "LevelOne",
  "Folder" : "LevelTwo"
}, {
  "Folder" : "LevelOne",
  "Folder" : "LevelThree"
}, {
  "Folder" : "LevelTwo",
  "Folder" : "LevelFour"
}, {
  "Folder" : "Horror",
  "Folder" : "Werewolf"
}, and so on.
```

Instead of

```
{
    "folder": "LevelOne",
    "subfolders": [
        {
            "folder": "LevelTwo",
            "subfolders": [
                {
                    "folder": "LevelFour",
                    "subfolders": [
                        {
                            "folder": "LevelSix"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "folder": "LevelFive"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "folder": "LevelThree"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please can you advise on how to format it like this?

Comment: the questions needs reformatting.. what does folder and subfolder signify ?

Comment: The parent and the child for example "Levelone" is the parent the child would be "LevelTwo" however "LevelTwo" is also a parent then it will have its own subfolders

Comment: What is ObjectNode ?

Comment: @SLA i think the answer below solves your problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

It's although not optimised and can be refactored.

Also, it doesn't handle the use-case where there exists two parents for same node.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("LevelOne | LevelTwo");
        values.add("LevelOne |LevelThree");
        values.add("LevelTwo | LevelFour");
        values.add("LevelTwo |LevelFive");
        values.add("LevelFour |LevelSix");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ArrayNode arrayNode = new ArrayNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance);

        for(String value : values){
            String parent = value.substring(0,value.indexOf("|")).trim();

            if(!arrayNode.findValuesAsText("folder").contains(parent)) {
                buildNode(values, mapper, arrayNode, parent);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(arrayNode));
    }
```

//THIS WILL START BUILDING THE NODE

```
     private static void buildNode(ArrayList<String> values, ObjectMapper mapper, ArrayNode arrayNode, String parent) {
            ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();

            rootNode.put("folder", parent);
            ArrayNode arrayNodeSubFolder = getSubFolders(values, mapper, parent);
            if(arrayNodeSubFolder.size() != 0)
                rootNode.put("subfolders", arrayNodeSubFolder);

            arrayNode.add(rootNode);
        }
```

//THIS WILL SCAN AND TRIGGER ADDING SUB NODE

```
    private static ArrayNode getSubFolders(ArrayList<String> values, ObjectMapper mapper, String parent) {
        ArrayNode arrayNode = new ArrayNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance);
        for (String val : values) {
            String currentParent = val.substring(0,val.indexOf("|")).trim();//Parent
            if(currentParent.equals(parent)) {
                String child = val.substring(val.indexOf("|") + 1).trim();//Child
                buildNode(values, mapper, arrayNode, child);
            }

        }
        return arrayNode;
    }
```

Also, i would recommend use of better data structure to represent the input data. However, this code is specifically as per your use-case

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, I'd suggest creating the tree structure already in the mysql, i.e. save the parent reference instead of child in a separate column. This eliminates redundancy:

```
FolderName  | Parent
-------------------------
"LevelOne"  | null
"LevelTwo"  | "LevelOne"
"LevelThree"| "LevelOne"
"LevelFour" | "LevelTwo"
"LevelFive" | "LevelTwo"
"LevelSix"  | "LevelFour"
```

After you load the entities into array list (6 elements), you can sort them according to the "parent" field (the order would be actually the same as in the table above. Lastly, when you iterate over the collection, you iterate the tree from the top to bottom, so in each iteration, create a node and add it to corresponding parent object. I would strongly suggest using Objects instead of strings as a representation of the tuple.